# LyX: Bibliography created two times with overlapping numbering

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, lyx

I have a little problem with my bibliography in LyX:
First, I insert a bibtex-bibliography (Insert -> List/TOC -> BibTeX Bibliography) at the end of my document (in the appendix). For that, I use a *.bib file generated by Citavi 4 (here literature.bib). But I also have some other references manually created in Lyx that I would like to use as reference.
Now, what I get are two bibliographies on two pages at the end of my document, each starting with [1], but I would like to have only one page of bibliography, both combined and no overlapping entries of [1].
If there any way of doing this in LyX without putting my manually added references in Citavi and creating a *bib file with all my references?

Here is the minimal Latex-code:

```
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
Look it up here: \cite{name1.2000}
Also interesting: \cite{my-ref}
\appendix
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{literature}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{my-ref}My reference
\end{thebibliography} 
\end{document}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can have two bibliography files in the argument of `\bibliography`. Put your additional references in a file `myrefs.bib` and call

```
\bibliography{literature,myrefs}
```